# Magento iPhone theme: How to show categories instead of main navigation bar?

Tags: iphone, magento, mobile-website, magento-1.9

I'm using default magento iPhone theme for mobile viewers of my website, but defaultly iPhone theme show main navigation bar on the home page. But I need to show category list instead of main navigation bar. How should I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by making a new phtml file called category.phtml in directory iPhone/template/catalog/navigation for category using http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/display-categories-and-subcategories-in-magento/ code.

Then I have called it to page.xml file in directory iPhone/layout inside my footer block

```
<block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.left" as="cat_left" template="catalog/navigation/category.phtml"/>

</block>
```

then after that I have simply called created category.phtml file in footer.phtml located in iphone/template/page/html using getChildHtml function like below

```
<div id="navigation">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cat_left')?></div>
```

hope this will help